# uniform convergence real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Find the limit function $$F(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} F_n(x)$$ and show that the convergence is uniform on closed subsets of S:

$$\begin{align}
(a) &&& F_n(x) = x^n \sin(nx); && S = (-1; 1)\\
(b) &&& F_n(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x^{2n}} ; && S = \{x|x \neq \pm 1\}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please give us your thoughts on the question so we know exactly what you are struggling with.

Comment: For a), note ptwise convergence to $0$. Now, clear by bounding by $x^n$; choose closed subset [-D, D] and we want $D^n < \varepsilon$ with $n > -\log(\varepsilon)/\log(D)$. This should give you fodder for last part.

Answer (score 1):

For (a) the pointwise limit is zero, so:

$|F_n-F|=|x^n\sin(nx)|\le|x|^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ $\forall x\in\,K\subset S$ where $K$ is closed.

But for (b) the convergence is not uniform since if $|x|\lt 1$ the limit is $1$, but if $|x|\gt 1$ the limit is $0$.

So it is not uniform on all closed subsets of $S$, but it may be on specific closed subsets.

Comment: Agreed, but it can on a closed subset since then $x$ does not get too close to $1$

Comment: But here $S=(-1,1)$ so any closed subset does not contain $1$...

Comment: Arg. Yes, the question asks for convergence **on closed subsets of S**, not on S. Silly me !!!

Comment: Lol, yeah and the bound I've put is uniform so it's definitely justified :)